# Using passport.js with DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, passport.js

I am new to node.js and I have made some simple static pages using ejs, and just recently began storing and retrieving data with DynamoDB on AWS.  Now, I want to make a simple user authentication app using passport for signup, login, and logout.

I found the following: https://github.com/christianboutin/passportjs-dynamodb

However, I'm not sure how to implement.  I I think i would add something like the following in my routes.js file:

```
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect : '/index',
    failureRedirect : '/signup1', 
    failureFlash : true 
}));
```

Is this the right approach?  Would I just include the passport.js file from the git repository in the routes.js file to achieve this?

Comment: No, you should use npm or yarn to install passport and the passport-dynamo strategy and then configure them. The modules each have docs explaining how.

Comment: I have installed passport using npm, but I cannot find passport-dynamo... it says not found.  Do you have a link?

Comment: To be clear, I am wanting to use the passport-local strategy with dynamodb as my database for storing user credentials...

Comment: ? You listed it in your question. I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

Install passport-local via npm or yarn, then just copy/paste the code from passport-dynamodb passport.js as you said to your existing project repo. passport-dynamodb is not published to npm, which is why you cannot install and import it as you normally would a nodeJS package like passport itself.